# Making a CentOS 6.x installation compatible with Xilinx ISE 14.7

Tags: centos, docker, glibc

I would like to run `version 14.7` of `Xilinx ISE`, which is a closed-source software. When it originally came out in 2013, it was supposed to be running on `RHEL 6`, so I think using `CentOS 6.x` should be my best option. `RHEL v6.4` and `RHEL v6.5` are the closest contemporaries of `ISE 14.7`.

However, when running either version (in a Docker container), the JVM bundled with the ISE fails when generating code for IP cores. I had tried to start `java` from the ISE installation, and it failed with a weird link-time error:

```
$ /sdk/fpga/Xilinx/14.7/ISE_DS/ISE/java/lin64/jre/bin/java 
dl failure on line 719Error: 
failed /sdk/fpga/Xilinx/14.7/ISE_DS/ISE/java/lin64/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so, 
because /sdk/fpga/Xilinx/14.7/ISE_DS/ISE/lib/lin64/libm.so.6: 
symbol __strtold_nan, version GLIBC_PRIVATE not defined in file libc.so.6 with link time reference
```

This is with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` set by some ISE scripts to:

```
/sdk/fpga/Xilinx/14.7/ISE_DS/ISE/lib/lin64:\
/sdk/fpga/Xilinx/14.7/ISE_DS/EDK/lib/lin64:\
/sdk/fpga/Xilinx/14.7/ISE_DS/common/lib/lin64
```

I've had some success running it on `Ubuntu 14.0`4 and `12.04` Docker images, where the `java` executable works (with the same `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` settings), but that too would crash with weird internal libc errors like double-`free`ing etc. from non-Java parts of the ISE; which is why I want to move on to `CentOS`.

*My question is:*

On a fresh version of `CentOS 6.5` or 6.4 Docker container, how do I fix glibc so that the JVM bundled with Xilinx ISE works?